# CentOS: Can't connect remotely to mysql server but I can 'nc' to it

Tags: centos, mysql, installation, moodle

I have two VMs, both running CentOS.

One is web server: 10.2.2.59
-- in this server I put Moodle web application files.

One is DB server: 10.2.2.58
I installed MySQL and it is running nice, changed `my.conf` to comment `#skipping-network` and commented  `#bind-address`.

I have config the firewall to accept port 3306

```
-A INPUT -s 10.3.2.59 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

---

On (.59) I tried to `nc -z  10.2.2.58 3306`
and the output is

```
Connection to 10.2.2.58 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
```

Also I tried to connect to mysql remotely from (.59) to (.58)
using `mysql -u moodle_XXXX_ur -p -h 10.2.2.58`

and it did connect and the `mysql>` prompt is showing.

I Grant 'moodle_XXXX_ur' all privileges to moodle_XXX_DB

---

The main problem is when I try to install moodle in (.59) with those parameters

```
Database host : 10.2.2.58
Database name : moodle_XXX_DB
Database user : moodle_XXXX_ur
Database password: XXXXXXXXXXXXX
Tables prefix: mdl_
Unix socket: true
```

I tried setting the Unix socket to `false` as well.

an error is showing saying that:

```
Error: Database connection failed

It is possible that the database is overloaded or otherwise not running properly.

The site administrator should also check that the database details have been correctly specified in config.php

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied in /var/www/html/lib/dml/mysqli_native_moodle_database.php on line 76
```

---

line 76 looks like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, '', $dbport, $dbsocket); // Connect without db
```

any help, or any way to trace the problem???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5769220/php-mysqli-query-permission-denied) it could be because of selinux policy. Try to turn selinux off on both servers. [Enable or Disable SELinux on CentOs](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/sec-sel-enable-disable.html)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a problem of   ["SELinux Booleans"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/linuxonibm/liaai.selinux/liaaiselinuxhttpdboolean.htm)
use the following comand to show the state of the boolean

```
$getsebool -a | grep httpd_can_network
```

and "httpd_can_network_connect_db" should be on

```
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> on
```

otherwise u have to turn on whit this command

```
$setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: Only `httpd_can_network_connect_db` is necessary here. It allows database ports. `httpd_can_network_connect` allows connections to all ports.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to say you have enabled the "skip-networking" option in MySQL.  If that's so, the server not to listen on the network.  In other words, if you have "skip-networking" on, you will only be able to talk to this server via a local UNIX socket and not from another server over the network.

To fix this, remove the "skip-networking" configuration line and restart MySQL, you should be able to connect then.

Please see MySQL documentation for more details on the "skip-networking" option - [MySQL 5.5 server options - skip-networking](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking)

If you didn't enable the "skip-networking" option, you need to double check the database parameters you supply the Moodle installer with, esp. make sure that "UNIX socket" is set to false.

Comment: He said that he "commented" the `skip-networking` option.  That would normally mean that networking is active.  The success of the `nc` command suggests that networking is working.

Answer (score -3):

I did turn selinux off on database server.

The solution was turn selinux off on **BOTH** servers.

many thanks to Kewa @kewa

Comment: Turning SELinux off is never the correct solution.